# Prove: if $\:\lim_\limits{x\to a}\:f(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a}\:g(x) = \infty$, then $\lim_\limits{x\to a}\:(f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $\:\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = \infty$, then$\:\forall$$m>0$$\:\exists d_1$ such that if$\:|x-a|< d_1$, then $f(x) > \Large\frac{m}{2}$.

If $\:\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow a}g(x) = \infty$, then$\:\forall$$m>0$$\:\exists d_2$ such that if$\:|x-a|< d_2$, then $g(x) > \Large\frac{m}{2}$.

Thus,$\:\forall m>0\:$let$\:d = \min(d_1, d_2)$.

Then if $\:|x - a| < d$,
$\:\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow\infty}\:[f(x) = g(x)] = f(x) + g(x) > \Large\frac{m}{2}\normalsize+\Large\frac{m}{2}\normalsize\geq m $

Does this look about right?

Thanks.

Comment: You need $D$ to be mininum of the two. Also, $\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x)]\not < M$

Comment: Ah yeah, wasn't thinking. How about now?

Comment: It's better now, but the line below the one you just edited still does not make sense (though I understand what you are saying). You really just need $|x-a|<D \implies f(x)+g(x)>M/2+M/2=M$

Comment: you don't need the M/2.  Just use $M$ and then you get $>2M>M$.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost correct. You should remove the last statement:

---

$$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) + g(x)] = f(x) + g(x) > M/2 + M/2 = M.$$

---

and replace it with

---

$$ f(x) + g(x) > M/2 + M/2 = M,$$

and, therefore $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) + g(x)] = \infty$.

---

The reason why the first statement is not entirely correct is because

$$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) + g(x)] \neq f(x) + g(x).$$